# setTimeOut not working (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

I have a div "pushBtns" and a anchor tag with the id "showPushBtns", the "pushBtns" will be hidden on pageload and appear in 5 secs after pageload. However, if user clicks on the anchor id "showPushBtns", it should stop the "timedShow()" function and div "pushBtns" should appear. The timed show hide function is working fine but I can't get the "clearTimeout" to work. Please assist?

P.S I am a beginner in jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  var theButtons = $("#pushBtns");
  theButtons.hide();
  function showIt(){
     theButtons.show(1000);
  }
  function timedShow() { 
     var timer = setInterval(function() {showIt();},5000);
  }
  timedShow();
  $('#showPushBtns').click(function(){
     clearTimeout(timer);
  });
});
</script>
```

ANSWERED
http://jsfiddle.net/pcvhG/6/

Thank you @mguimard

```
var theButtons = $("#pushBtns");
var togglBtn = $("#showPushBtns");
var timer;
$(document).ready(function() {
theButtons.hide();
function showIt(){theButtons.show(1000);}
function timedShow() { setTimeout(function() {showIt();},5000);}
timedShow();
$('#showPushBtns').click(function(){clearTimeout(timedShow());showIt()});
});
```

Comment: The setInterval and clearTimeout has nothing to do with jQuery...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`clearTimeout(timer)` just clears the timer so the function will never be ran. So you need to execute `showIt()` after clearing the timer.

```
$('#showPushBtns').click(function()
{
   clearTimeout(timer);
   showIt();
});
```

Edit: also noticed you are using `setInterval`. Did you mean to use `setTimeout` there?

Answer (score 3):

Use `clearInterval`, not `clearTimeout`.

Or instead, use `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout`, should be more appropriate for your needs. Why should you call `showIt` every 5 seconds ?

Comment: Many errors in your fiddle, ducplicate Ids, wrong assignments. Here's a working example : http://jsfiddle.net/pcvhG/6/

Answer (score 0):

Your timer variable is local to your timedShow function -make it global and you need to use `clearInterval`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var timer;
    var theButtons = $("#pushBtns");
    theButtons.hide();

    function showIt() {
        theButtons.show(1000);
    }

    function timedShow() {
       timer = setInterval(function () {
            showIt();
        }, 5000);
    }
    timedShow();
    $('#showPushBtns').click(function () {
        clearInterval(timer);
    });
});
```

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval